# Spring Remoting Services (via HTTPInvoker) is more lightweight than EJB 3.1 Stateless?

Tags: performance, spring, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, spring-remoting

I have two java web-app in the same application server (JBoss 7). And one web-app makes some remote calls to the other one.

Today I'm using Stateless EJB 3.1 to expose the services. Do you think that exposing the services with Spring Remoting (via httpinvoke or hessian) performs better?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you currently expose the EJB via @WebService, there is a good chance that Hessian would be faster since it is a binary protocol.

The standard webservice serializer (JAXB) is fairly wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see a benchmark of remoting technologies:

http://daniel.gredler.net/2008/01/07/java-remoting-protocol-benchmarks/